# Won't add a default custom row on combobox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

been having an issue displaying an empty item as default selected item on a combobox. This combobox is a filter for my gridview and currently my datagridview displays all data based on the first item of the combobox but what i wanted is to have an empty first combobox item so that datagridview will pull all data from database. When i run the app it says

> System.ArgumentException: 'Input string was not in a correct
>   format.Couldn't store <> in ailment_id Column.  Expected type is
>   Int32.'

My code to populate combobox from database:

```
Private Sub populateComboAilment()
        data_adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ailment", myconnection.open())
        Dim data_table As New DataTable

        data_adapter.Fill(data_table)

        'assign default value
        Dim row As datarow = data_table.NewRow()
        row(0) = ""
        data_table.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)


        comboAilment.DataSource = data_table
        With comboAilment
            .DisplayMember = "name"
            .ValueMember = "ailment_id"
        End With

        myconnection.close()
End Sub
```

> Update: All is working now when I changed combobox ValueMember to a
>   `name` since it's an id before. but when I select another item it
>   displays nothing on the gridview because my datagridview query doesn't
>   know the name, only id since it's a foreign key.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error message is fairly plain and unambiguous. Why would you expect to be able to store a `String` containing "<>" in a column that expects numbers and specifically `Integer` values? Why you even try in the first place?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, thanks for the response. Is there any workaround to set default item to empty cos I wanted to have a empty item on the very top of my combobox items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I just looked more carefully at the code and you're not actually assigning a `String` containing "<>" but rather an empty `String`.  It doesn't really matter though.  A `String` is a `String` and you can't put one where a number is required.  You might be able to use a `String` that contained digits because that could be implicitly converted to a number but a empty `String` doesn't qualify.

If you want an empty field in a `DataRow` then you need to do what ADO.NET does to represent a database null, i.e. use `DBNull.Value`.  That means an object of type `DBNull`, which is required because ADO.NET predates nullable value types.  You can't just use `Nothing` because would work for reference types but not value types, e.g. if you assign `Nothing` to an `Integer` variable you are effectively setting it to zero.

In short, you need to change this:

```
Dim row As datarow = data_table.NewRow()
row(0) = DBNull.Value
row(1) = DBNull.Value
data_table.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)
```

In the case of the `name` column, its data type is `String` so you could use an empty `String` there (preferably `String.Empty` rather than "" but either works) but null is more appropriate because it is actually no value, rather than a value containing no characters.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I managed to fix the issue from your advice.